# how to add preloader for 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

I need to run a loader (#loading) for 3 seconds  .
is the below script correct?

```js
<script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#loading').show();3000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: remove first <script> tag

Answer (score 1):

maybe you don't need the '$(window).load()'.

```js
$('#loading').show().delay(3000).hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the script tag.

You can use `setTimeout()` to remove something after 3 seconds.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#loading').fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading">
  Look at me, I'm a load screen
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#loading').show().delay( 3000 ).fadeOut( 400 );

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$('#loading').show(0).delay(3000).hide(0);
```